# React Material UI RadioGroup not working with FormControlLabel returned by component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an issue working with the material UI RadioGroup in combination with FormControlLabels returned by a component.

Currently I try this:

```
<FormControl component="fieldset">
  <RadioGroup
    row
    name="genreSelection"
    className="genre-wrapper"
    value={this.state.selection}
    onChange={this.handleRadioSelection}
  >
  {
    this.state.genres.map(genre => (
      <GenreItem key={genre} label={genre} radioButton/>
    ))
  }
  </RadioGroup>
</FormControl>
```

And the render function of *GenreItem* looks like this:

```
if (this.props.radioButton) {
  return (
    <FormControlLabel
      value={this.props.label}
      label={this.props.label}
      control={
        <Radio/>
      }
      className="genre-item"
    />
  );
}
// Another return here
```

My problem is that the *FormControlLabel* isn't working correctly as *"handleRadioSelection"* isn't triggered on any selection.

By now I found out that the input element generated from the Radio element doesn't have *name="genreSelection"* as attribute which means it doesn't belong to the RadioGroup defined above.

If I put the *FormControlLabel* out of *GenreItem* and directly into the *this.state.genres.map* function everything is working just fine.

Am I doing something wrong or is this just a limitation of material UI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the code of [RadioGroup](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/RadioGroup/RadioGroup.js) you'll find that it clones the children that you provide to it and adds several properties. You need to carry those properties down into `FormControlLabel`. 
You can accomplish that by changing `GenreItem` to render the `FormControlLabel` as follows:

```
// assign radioButton separately so it isn't part of labelProps
const { radioButton, ...labelProps } = this.props;
if (radioButton) {
    <FormControlLabel {...labelProps }
      label={this.props.value}
      control={
        <Radio/>
      }
      className="genre-item"
    />
```

Adding `{...labelProps}` will carry forward the props added by RadioGroup.

Also if you want the label and value to be the same, it is important to pass `value` explicitly to `GenreItem` rather than `label` since `RadioGroup` uses the `value` prop to help determine the `checked` property.

Here's a working example:

[image: Edit pk50jkxqz7]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With the changes you suggested I get ```Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `radiobutton`.```. Look like the label element can't handle my attribute. The workaround I found is to add ```radiobutton="something"``` to the FormControlLabel. But this is a really dirty. Moreover I now have to handle the checked attribute of the Radio element by myself...

Comment: Thanks! Looking good now. Even though I have to set the checked attribute on the Radio element by myself. But that is totally fine for me.

Comment: You shouldn’t have to set anything on the Radio element. My example isn’t.

Comment: I realized why checked isn't working for you, see my updated answer (you need to pass value explicitly to GenreItem).

Comment: Yes, that did the final trick! I would have never found out about that >_> Thank you very much :)