# onChange could not be triggered in radioGroup with material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I'm using `RadioButton`component to display different options of a question in a component which I created:

```
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Radio from "@material-ui/core/Radio";
import RadioGroup from "@material-ui/core/RadioGroup/RadioGroup";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import SyntaxHighlighter from "react-syntax-highlighter";
import { dark } from "react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/prism";
import { Dispatch } from "redux";
import { incrementQuestion, IQuestion, questionRequest } from "../../actions/index";
import ContentQuiz from "../../components/ContentQuiz";
import history from "../../history/history";

interface IProps {
  currentQuestionNumber: number;
  loadingData: boolean;
  questions: IQuestion[];
  questionRequest: () => void;
  incrementQuestion: (arg: number) => void;
  numberOfQuestions: number;
}

const Quiz = (props: IProps) => {
  const { currentQuestionNumber,
    loadingData,
    questions,
    questionRequest,
    incrementQuestion,
    numberOfQuestions } = props;

  const [answerOption, setAnswerOption] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    questionRequest();
  }, [questionRequest]);

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setAnswerOption(Number((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value));
  };
  const handleNextQuiz = () => {
    if (currentQuestionNumber === numberOfQuestions - 1) {
      history.push("/homepage");
    } else {
      incrementQuestion(answerOption);
      history.push("/contentQuiz");
    }
  };

  const currentQuestion = questions[currentQuestionNumber];
  return (
    <div>
      {loadingData ? ("Loading ...") : (
        < ContentQuiz
          questionNumber={currentQuestionNumber + 1}
          handleClick={handleNextQuiz} >
          <div>
            <Typography variant="h3" gutterBottom> What's the output of </Typography>
            <>
              <SyntaxHighlighter language="javascript" style={dark} >
                {currentQuestion.description.replace(";", "\n")}
              </SyntaxHighlighter >
                <Grid container direction="column" alignItems="baseline">
                  <Grid>
                    <FormControl component="fieldset">
                      <RadioGroup
                        name="option"
                        value={answerOption}
                        onChange={handleChange}>
                        {currentQuestion.options.map((option: string, index: number) => (
                          <FormControlLabel
                            key={index}
                            control={<Radio color="secondary" />}
                            label={option}
                            value={index + 1}
                            labelPlacement="end"
                          />))
                        }
                      </RadioGroup>
                    </FormControl>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </>
          </div >
        </ContentQuiz >
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
  const { currentQuestionNumber, loadingData, questions, numberOfQuestions } = state.quiz;

  return {
    currentQuestionNumber,
    loadingData,
    questions,
    numberOfQuestions
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  return {
    incrementQuestion: (answer: any) => dispatch<any>(incrementQuestion(answer)),
    questionRequest: () => dispatch<any>(questionRequest())
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Quiz);
```

However, it is possible to check different options with this code and according to [Radio buttons](https://material-ui.com/components/radio-buttons/#radio-button) the normal behavior is only one option could be checked.
I find a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53980379/react-material-ui-radiogroup-not-working-with-formcontrollabel-returned-by-compo) and tried to update my code according to the answer but it does not work because in my case the `handleChange` function is not called and I don't know why?

Comment: Convert the value parameter of FormControlLabel to String and the selection of radio buttons will start working. `value={(index + 1).toString()}`

Answer (score -1):

As I could understand from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53980379/react-material-ui-radiogroup-not-working-with-formcontrollabel-returned-by-compo) provided by you, you can try the following:

1. Add the below functional component:

   ```
   const FormControlLabelWrapper = props => {
   const { index, option, ...labelProps } = props;
         return (
           <FormControlLabel
             key={index}
             control={<Radio color="secondary" />}
             label={option}
             value={index + 1}
             labelPlacement="end"
             {...labelProps}
           />
         );
       };
   ```
2. Change the `currentQuestion.options.map` to below code

   ```
   {currentQuestion.options.map((option: string, index: number) => 
   (<FormControlLabelWrapper
     option={option}
     index={index}
    />))}
   ```